# JavaScript find the sentence with the most words

Tags: javascript, string, match

I need to know why this is wrong... I am trying to create a function that finds the sentence with the most words in it and to return the number of words. It looks for dots . question marks ? and exclamation marks !

```
const numberOfWords = (string) => {
  let sentenceArray = string.match(/.*?[?!.]/g)
  let mostWords =
    sentenceArray.reduce((sentence1, sentence2) => 
    (sentence1.split('').length < sentence2.split   ('').length ?
        sentence1 = sentence2
        :
        sentence1
    )) 
  return mostWords.split(' ').length
}
```

This has worked with this string as a test: "This is a sentence. This is another? I think?"

returning 4 but in some cases, it adds an extra number to it? I want to understand why! Like this: "How about this one? Wait! I think this should be the longest. I think this one should be the longest even longer." 
// returns the last sentence as 11 words but it should be 10.

Comment: your punctuation marks have spaces after them, so when you split, you'll get an additional string which adds to your total length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) the string before splitting and taking the *length*:

```js
const numberOfWords = (string) => {
  let sentenceArray = string.match(/.*?[?!.]/g)
  let mostWords =
    sentenceArray.reduce((sentence1, sentence2) => 
    (sentence1.trim().split('').length < sentence2.trim().split('').length ?
        sentence1 = sentence2
        :
        sentence1
    )) 
  return mostWords.trim().split(' ').length
}
console.log(numberOfWords(`How about this one?Wait! I think this should be the longest. I think this one should be the longest even longer.`))
```

Comment: You should also trim it when comparing sentences.

Comment: @RoderickCardenas, you are most welcome, the white space (in the start and end) were counted as characters:)

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this

```
const numberOfWords = (string) => {
    let sentenceArray = string.split(/[?!.,\/-]/);
    console.log(sentenceArray);
    let mostWords =
        sentenceArray.sort((sentence1, sentence2) =>
            sentence1.trim().split(' ').length + sentence2.trim().split(' ').length)
    return mostWords[0].trim().split(' ').length
}
```